# Installed ubuntu 16 from external drive to HP laptop stuck on grub

Tags: boot, grub2

I installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS from external drive onto an HP laptop (64 bit). I am not running dual OS, only ubuntu. It said the install was sucessfull and to restart the computer to run it. It restarted and is on the grub screen (which i know nothing about). What do I do to move forward?

Comment: what are the options on grub screen? if ubuntu is there then select it and press Enter

Comment: the options are: Try ubuntu without installing, Install Ubuntu, OEM install, check disc for defects

Answer (score 0):

Powered down the computer. Unplugged the external drive that was used to install Ubuntu and then powered the computer up. Success! Ubuntu is now running